# jquery div slider: div hide before fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a jQuery slider that fades between some divs but the exit effect (fadeOut) occurs after the div has been hidden. It might be simple but I can't fix this myself.
http://jsbin.com/uqovih/689/edit

Help anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick. The idea is to fadeout first, then carry on with rest of the animation.

```
$("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slider > div:first').fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slider');
  });

},  3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
jQuery(el).fadeOut(duration, function(){
    //hide here
})
```